# Unable to initialize Leaflet.draw toolbar

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I am having difficulty initializing the [Leaflet.draw toolbar](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). I've tried using code from various examples and still cannot get the toolbar to display on my map. My code exists in its own .js file and is shown below:

```js
function main() {

// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map('map', {
    drawControl: true
}).setView([35.110756 , -120.591667], 14);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiemFjaHJvYmluc29uIiwiYSI6IjZXWDh0enMifQ.P_x5U3esb8BJM9apOhn4Kg', {
    attribution: '© Mapbox © OpenStreetMap © DigitalGlobe'
}).addTo(map);


// Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topleft',
    draw: {
        marker: true
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
    
map.on('draw:created', function(e){
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    
    if (type === 'marker'){
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }
    
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

}

window.onload = main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you copied all the required external .js files.
Leaflet.draw requires

- leaflet.css
- leaflet.draw.css
- leaflet.js
- leaflet.draw.js

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

Script:

```
function main() {

  // create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
  var map = L.map('map', {
    drawControl: true
  }).setView([35.110756, -120.591667], 14);

  // add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
  L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiemFjaHJvYmluc29uIiwiYSI6IjZXWDh0enMifQ.P_x5U3esb8BJM9apOhn4Kg', {
    attribution: '© Mapbox © OpenStreetMap © DigitalGlobe'
  }).addTo(map);


  // Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
  var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
  map.addLayer(drawnItems);


  map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
      layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
      layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
  });
}
window.onload = main();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silverhawk/dw9jok46/

Comment: Thank you, Uchiha! I was not properly linking to the required Leaflet CSS/JS files.